# Could we say that each class that define an event in C# is a subject of an observer pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I would like to understand. In C# could we say that each class that define an event is a subject of an (hypothetical) observer pattern?

Comment: Note that the observer pattern doesn't *demand* that it be implemented via delegate-based events - for example, you can implement an observer in java and other delegate-less languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Though there is also an IObserver Interface in the .NET Framework, events are the best way to do it. You can read [Microsoft's desctiption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx#observerpattern_topic3b) on the matter.

Comment: I would highly argue with events always being the best way to do it. Nowadays I often use an IObservable to wrap events and subscribe with IObservers...

Comment: Rx operators mainly - throttle, observeondispatcher, where, selectmany just to name my favorites